# Using sample(..., replace = FALSE) in a tidy Monte Carlo simulation using crossing

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyverse, montecarlo

I am working through [Digital Dice by Paul Nahin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691126984) to teach myself Monte Carlo simulations. I am converting the Matlab code in the book to R code on the first pass, then replacing for-loops with tidy versions on the second pass.

Edit: Here is what I am looking to model:

- Imagine that you face a pop quiz, a list of the 24 Presidents of the 19th century and another list of their terms in office but scrambled
- The object is to match the President with the term
- You get one guess every time
- On average, how many do you guess correct?

Here is the R code using for-loops:

```
m <- 24
total_correct <- 0
n <- 10000

for (i in 1:n) {
  correct <- 0
  term <- sample(m, replace = TRUE)
  for (j in 1:m) {
    if (term[j] == j) {
      correct <- correct + 1
    }
  }
  total_correct = total_correct + correct
}
total_correct <- total_correct / n
print(total_correct)
```

This works (but I admit gives the wrong answer). Next is to tidy-fy this -- this is my attempt:

```
crossing(trials = 1:10, 
         m = 1:24) %>% 
  mutate(guess = sample.int(24, n(), replace = F), result = m == guess) %>% 
  summarise(score = sum(result) / n())
```

However, I get an error message reading

> Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob): cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

I understand what's going on: The `n()` command in the `mutate()` statement returns 240. Sampling 240 from a population 24 with `replace = FALSE` is nonsensical hence the error message.

How do I get the `mutuate()` statement to receive a size of 24 on each iteration (or trial)?

Comment: What the heck are you trying to model?

Comment: I don't understand, if you want `n()` to always be 24, why not just hard code it as 24? Do you want it to be more general? Do you want it to be the number of unique values of m? You can use `length(unique(m))`. So maybe you wanted to group by trails with `group_by(trials)` to do operations within each? I'm really not sure what you want though. I suggest using words to describe to us exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Maybe you want `crossing(trials = 1:10, m = 1:24) %>% group_by(trials) %>% group_by(trials) %>% mutate(guess = sample.int(24, n()), result = m == guess)`?

Comment: Using `set.seed(1)` this returns 11 TRUE and 229 FALSE values, or about 4.6% TRUE, which is not so far away from the expected value of 4.2% - I'd imagine this converges as `nrows()` approaches infinity.